# Encender y apagar led o luz con GPIO Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Estoy con mi raspberry intentando encender un led y apagarlo con scripts distintos y no van.
Para depurar el error tengo el siguiente script en python que se encarga de que el led parpadee:

```
#Importamos la libreria y le cambiamos el nombre a GPIO
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#Necesario para los delays
import time

#Establecemos el sistema de numeracion que queramos, 
#en este caso el sistema BCM
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#Configuramos el pin GPIO 17 como una salida
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)

#Encendemos y apagamos el led 3 veces
for i in range(0,3):

        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)

#Y liberamos los GPIO
GPIO.cleanup()
```

El script de parpadeo funciona perfectamente.
Para depurarlo he comentado el bucle for para que solo lo apague o lo encienda y resulta que solo con que quite la linea del bucle ya no hace nada y deja de funcionar.

Es decir, puedo hacer que el led parpadee utilizando el bucle, pero no puedo hacer que solo se encienda o solo se apague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final logré resolverlo, si queremos hacer que parpadee, mi implementación con el bucle for es corrrecta. Pero si solo queremos apagarlo o encenderlo, hay que hacer setup al pin configurándolo como salida o entrada respectivamente.

Por lo que solo habría que quitar el bucle for, y cambiar la línea anterior `GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)` según lo que queramos:

ENCENDER:

```
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.cleanup() #liberamos el pin
```

APAGAR:

```
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
```

- *Esta configuración puede ser al revés, ya que yo tengo conectada mi raspberry pi a un relé configurado como normalmente cerrado, entonces cuando mando la señal al relé (*`GPIO.OUT`*) abre el circuito y apaga la luz.*

Previamente conviene desactivar los warnings con `GPIO.setwarnings(False)` después de importar la librería de los pines y a continuación establecer el sistema de numeración.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que el led siga encendido puedes sacar el `for` y luego de encender el LED poner un loop infinito:

```
GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: es una implementación muy poco eficiente, el script se quedaría ejecutando indefinidamente